# How do i extract elements from javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a result from my ajax call:

```
function getNames() {
  var names=[];
  (myAjaxCallHere).success(result) {
     for(i in result) {
        names.firstname = result[i].firstname;
     }
     return names;
  }
}
```

when I call the function getNames

```
var names = getNames();
console.log(names);
```

the result is:

```
>[]
```

when i expand, the result is :

```
v Array[0]
    firstname:"JohnDoe"
    length:0
    > __proto__:Array[0]
```

I tried to extract:

```
var names = getNames();
console.log(names.firstname);
```

but the result is `undefined`

I tried also

```
for(i in names) {
  console.log(names[i].firstname);
}
```

but still no luck.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of undefined
```

How do I print firstnames in console using javascript?
This is my first step to learn javascript. Please help. thanks :)

Comment: You're using `return names;` which is not actually returned. Please see the answers on the linked question to see ways to solve this problem.

Comment: what is the structure of `result`?